# How to remove an account from Google Hangouts?

Tags: security, google-account, privacy, password, google-hangouts

I logged in to Google Hangouts using an account (which is NOT the account I use in play store). But now I cannot remove it. I can sign out, but to sign back in, it does not for the password and automatically signs in. I don't want just anyone to be able to pick up my phone from the table and log in to my personal account.

So how to remove that account from hangouts or at least make it forget the password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to revoke access to that account from your phone -- or simply from Hangouts/Talk if it is listed -- through [this page](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?hl=en).

When you add a new account to Hangouts, Android automatically adds it to your globally accessible accounts (Settings > Accounts). As far as I know, there is no way to activate temporary log-in sessions.

Comment: Isn't there any simple way just to sign out from that account without my password being stored? Do I have to go to that page and revoke access every time I want to log in? :(

Comment: When you add a new account to Hangouts, Android automatically adds it to your globally accessible accounts (Settings > Accounts). As far as I know, there is no way to activate temporary log-in sessions.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I deleted the account from Settings --> Accounts. That works :) If you edit your answer and add the last comment you made in the answer, then I can mark it as accepted.